# Install Laravel Nova on Gitlab CI

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, laravel-nova

I'm trying to use a continuous Integration with Gitlab CI.

I installed a fresh Laravel 8, add manually  `"laravel/nova": "~3.0",` in `composer.json`

As stated in [docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/installation.html#installing-nova-via-composer), I do

```
composer config http-basic.nova.laravel.com ${NOVA_USERNAME} ${NOVA_PASSWORD}
```

and then

```
➜ composer update                      
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/nova, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I echoed `${NOVA_USERNAME} ${NOVA_PASSWORD}` and I have doubled check that both field are OK. `NOVA_USERNAME` contains the registered email, and `NOVA_PASSWORD` contains the API Token found here: https://nova.laravel.com/settings/password

Anybody knows where am I failing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is  because you didn't add the Nova repository to your `composer.json` file. It is mentioned in the documentation link you provided.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://nova.laravel.com"
    }
],
```